# Android Bluetooth: fetchUuidsWithSdp() does not return all UUIDs on some devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have two different bluetooth apps. The first provides a service and listens to commands from the other commander app. I have a GT-I9100T phone and a GT-P5210 tablet. The tablet when acting at the listener works fine and the phone can see the UUID for my app. But when I run the phone as the listener, the UUID of the listener is not listed.

I filter the devices by my application UUID so that I know I am talking only to those devices with my application running.

My listening app looks like this (I get the same result if I use an insecure connection as well):

```
private final UUID GUID = UUID.fromString("3DEF793A-FA94-4478-AE56-108854B1EF4B");
// other stuff....
tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(APP_NAME, GUID);
```

My commander app MainActivity looks likes this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG,"Action received: "+action);
        if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID)) {
             BluetoothDevice btd = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
             Log.i(TAG,"Received uuids for "+btd.getName());
             Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             List<String> uuids = new ArrayList<String>(uuidExtra.length);
             if(uuidExtra != null) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < uuidExtra.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(uuidExtra[i].toString()).append(',');
                    uuids.add(uuidExtra[i].toString());
                 }
             }
             Log.i(TAG,"ACTION_UUID received for "+btd.getName()+" uuids: "+sb.toString());
             ListContent.addItemWithUUIDs(btd, uuids);
        }
    }
}
```

My list content (I am using the master/detail template):

```
public static synchronized void addItem(BluetoothItem item) {
        BluetoothDevice btd = item.mBluetoothDevice;
        Log.i(TAG,"Attempting to add "+item.mBluetoothDevice.getName());
        if(ITEMS.contains(item)) {
            Log.i(TAG,item.mBluetoothDevice.getName()+" already in list");
            return;
        }
        // Do we know this device?
        Parcelable[] uuids =  btd.getUuids();
        Set<String> setUUIDs = new HashSet<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(uuids != null) {
            for (Parcelable parcelable : uuids) {
                sb.append(parcelable.toString()).append(',');
                setUUIDs.add(parcelable.toString());
            }
        }
        Log.v(TAG,"Device has uuids: "+sb.toString());
        if ((btd.getUuids() != null && setUUIDs.contains(BluetoothItem.GUID.toLowerCase()))){
            Log.i(TAG, "Found app device: " + btd.getName());
            addItem(btd);
        } else {
            // If we don't know this device, perform sdp fetch of uuids
            Log.i(TAG,"Requesting fresh UUIDs for: "+btd.getName());
            // this is flushed when discovering finishes
            CANDIDATES.add(btd);
        }
    }
    public static synchronized void addItemWithUUIDs(BluetoothDevice btd, List<String> uuids) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Attempting to add with uuids"+btd.getName()+" uuids: "+btd.getUuids());
        if (uuids.contains(BluetoothItem.GUID)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found app device: " + btd.getName());
            addItem(btd);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring device " + btd.getName() + " without app guid");
        }
    }
```

When discovery is finished, this happens:

```
for (BluetoothDevice i : ListContent.CANDIDATES) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Fetching UUIDs for "+i.getName());
    i.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
}
ListContent.CANDIDATES.clear();
```

The logcat output when using the tablet as the commander and phone as listener:

```
DeviceListActivity(29524): Received uuids for GT-I9100T
DeviceListActivity(29524): ACTION_UUID received for GT-I9100T uuids:
0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
```

I get the correct output with phone as commander and tablet as listener:

```
DeviceListActivity(23121): Received uuids for GT-P5210
DeviceListActivity(23121): ACTION_UUID received for GT-P5210 uuids:
00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
3def793a-fa94-4478-ae56-108854b1ef4b,
```

As you can see, the GUID for my app is listed as the last item. I've tried making the devices discoverable and bonding and unbonding, but the GUID for my app is never returned for the phone. I have other non-Android devices that also use this GUID and they are discovered normally as well.

The phone is running 4.1.2 and the tablet is 4.2.2

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem, but with my desktop advertising.

Comment: I found no soultion. The best you can do is just try to connect using the GUID and seeing if it connects successfully.

Comment: Same problem....... if anybody knows how to do.....

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Currently struggling with the same thing.

Comment: @dustedrob I never fixed the  problem. I assume it's a bug in the firmware. My previous comment has a potential solution.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, using Android Wear on a Sony Smartwatch Series 3 : my UUID is not among the fetched UUIDs :/ Although, the direct connection does work.