# Can't find Bluetooth service using Android application

Tags: android, c, bluetooth

After launch a BLUETOOTH server written in c.

https://github.com/RyanGlScott/BluetoothTest/blob/master/C%20BlueZ%20Server/bluez_server.c

This is the output of the command sdptool browse local:

```
....other services....

    Service Name: AVRCP CT
    Service RecHandle: 0x10005
    Service Class ID List:
      "AV Remote" (0x110e)
    Protocol Descriptor List:
      "L2CAP" (0x0100)
        PSM: 23
      "AVCTP" (0x0017)
        uint16: 0x103
    Profile Descriptor List:
      "AV Remote" (0x110e)
        Version: 0x0100


    /*MY SERVICE!!!*/
    Service Name: Armatus Bluetooth server
    Service Description: A HERMIT server that interfaces with the Armatus Android app
    Service Provider: Armatus
    Service RecHandle: 0x10006
    Service Class ID List:
      "Serial Port" (0x1101)
    Protocol Descriptor List:
      "L2CAP" (0x0100)
      "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
        Channel: 3
    Profile Descriptor List:
      "Serial Port" (0x1101)
        Version: 0x0100

....other services....
```

I'am trying to find this service using an Android app

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // Whenever a remote Bluetooth device is found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = 
                intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                adapter.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n"
                        + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());


                if (bluetoothDevice.getName().equals("mint-0")) {
                    Log.d("tagmint0","bene bene");

                    try {

                    ParcelUuid[] uuids = (ParcelUuid[])  bluetoothDevice.getUuids();


                    for (ParcelUuid uuid : uuids) {
                        Log.d("x", "mintUUIDxx: " + uuid.getUuid().toString() + "\n");

                    }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

My question is, why my android application is not able to find my service even if it is visible using the command sdptool browse local?

This is the android application output

```
mintUUIDxx: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
mintUUIDxx: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

As you can see it doesn't contains the server uuid. Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

> bluetoothDevice.getUuids();

This method does not start a service discovery procedure to retrieve the UUIDs from the remote device. Instead, the local cached copy of the service UUIDs are returned.

Use `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` instead. This method perform a service discovery on the remote device to get the UUIDs supported.

Comment: It returns a booleans, so I use it in this way:
`bluetoothDevice.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
                    ParcelUuid[] uuids = (ParcelUuid[])  bluetoothDevice.getUuids();


                    for (ParcelUuid uuid : uuids) {
                        Log.d("x", "mintUUIDxx: " + uuid.getUuid().toString() + "\n");

                    }`


but nothing changes..

Comment: @Franconet You can try to connect with device using your own service's UUID. More information is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658426/android-bluetooth-fetchuuidswithsdp-does-not-return-all-uuids-on-some-devices).

Answer (score 0):

if you have used the same git code then looks like you have mention different UUID in android.
In you bluez_server.c

```
uint32_t svc_uuid_int[] = { 0x01110000, 0x00100000, 0x80000080, 0xFB349B5F };
```

And android output

```
mintUUIDxx: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Give a try by changing that line in bluez_server.c with this

```
uint32_t svc_uuid_int[] = { 0x0000111e, 0x00001000, 0x80000080, 0x5f9b34fb };
```

Comment: I have used the same UUID in both the applications. By the way, thank you :)

Comment: I have used following rfcomm-server.c this is little bit modified and this is receiving data all OK from Android application BlueTerm:-https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm&hl=en

Code:- http://pastebin.com/ntpNkaJS